Biologist Wagner reported some work on the history of a group of lizards called Bachia. => Does this mean this is his work or others' work he reported

Biologist Wagner reported some work on the history of a group of lizards called Bachia.

What does the bolded part mean? Did Wagner report his own work or did he read and report others' work? Can we tell?
I'm asking this because I wonder if there's any hidden nuance of the word "report" that non-native speakers might not know. At first, I thought he reported others' work since if he'd reported his work, I imagined it should have been "reported his work" instead. But now that I think more carefully about it, I realize it might also be his work, mightn't it?

Without context, it's impossible to be certain. I would assume it was his own work because it doesn't say 'some work by XXX', but  maybe the researchers were mentioned in another sentence? Please tell us where you read this.

Is this from the IELTS test 'When Evolution Runs Backwards'? Looks you shortened this:  In a paper published last year, biologist Gunter Wagner of Yale University reported some work on the evolutionary history of a group of South American lizards called Bachia. Google shows he worked with Tiana Kohlsdorf and they jointly authored a paper - maybe the creator of the test  thinks that only men are important? The history of science is littered with women whose work is credited to men.

@MichaelHarvey Thanks for quoting that. It's likely that the test creator mentioned only one author to make the question easier.

@KateBunting There's no more relevant information, but Tim's suggestion seems to shed some light on this.

They could have used Professor Tiana Kohlsdorf, whose name precedes Wagner's in the author list under the title of their joint paper

It means he did not report all the work.

"work" is a very broad term that means "efforts" and work in a scientific context could include "field work" and work in the lab, for example.
"To report work" is like "to report crime", to make it known to someone. You would report crime to the police and report work of a scientific nature in a scientific journal or at a conference, where you would deliver a paper, provide data in the form of charts, and then might sit on a panel for a Q&A session.
But all the phrase  means is "to make some work known by providing details about it."
Whether it would be understood to mean "his own work" or work on which he had collaborated would be something revealed in the text. It is highly unlikely that anyone is going to report work done by others with whom they had not collaborated.


Biologist Wagner reported some work on the history of a group of lizards called Bachia.

It's not clear if Wagner did the work or if it's someone else's work. There's no nuance to the word report.
Ways it could be clairified:

Wagner reported some work by field scientists in Guinea on the history of a group of lizards called Bachia.
Wagner reported some work he recently did on the history of a group of lizards called Bachia.

